# Dictionary replaces substrings Python 2.7

Tags: python, replace, substring

I want to replace numbers from a text file in a new text file. I tried to solve it with the function Dictionary, but now python also replaces the substrings.

For Example: I want to replace the number 014189 to 1489, with this code it also replaces 01489**6** to 1489 - how can i get rid of this? Thank you!!!

```
replacements = {'01489':'1489', '01450':'1450'}
infile = open('test_fplan.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('test_fplan_neu.txt', 'w')


for line in infile:
    for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(src, target)
    outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: It looks like the question may contain a few typos that could cause confusing. When you wrote 014189, should that have been just 01489? Also, does the code really replace 014896 to 1489, or rather, to 14896? (I don't think it would remove the 6).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your input file looks, but if the numbers are surrounded by spaces, this should work:

```
replacements = {' 01489 ':' 1489 ', ' 01450 ':' 1450 '}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answers! Helped a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your concern is that it's also modifying numbers that contain your src pattern as a substring. To avoid that, you'll need to first define the boundaries that should be respected. For instance, do you want to insist that only matched numbers surrounded by spaces get replaced? Or perhaps just that there be no adjacent digits (or periods or commas). Since you'll probably want to use regular expressions to constrain the matching, as suggested by JoshuaF in another answer, you'll likely need to avoid the simple replace function in favor of something from the re library.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp with negative lookarounds:

```
import re

replacements = {'01489':'1489', '01450':'1450'}

def find_replacement(match_obj):
    number = match_obj.group(0)
    return replacements.get(number, number)

with open('test_fplan.txt') as infile:
    with open('test_fplan_neu.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(
             re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(\d+)(?!\d)', find_replacement, line)
             for line in infile
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the regular expression syntax https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. It should allow you to match whatever pattern you're looking for exactly.